# Is it possible to create new funcitonality for classes in a library (Eigen) without editing the source file? (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, glm-math

## Context

I was forced to switch from glm to Eigen only because eigen can handle dimensions beyond 4 and I don;t want to have 2 different lin alg libraries at the same time. As far as usability goes, Eigen is infinitely times worse than glm. Consider the simple operation of concatenating 2 vectors:

GLM: `vec4(v1, v2);`

Eigen: `Vector4f v; v << v1, v2;`

GLM can be done in place which means you can append in the call to a function or in the middle of a complex line with multiple math operations.

With the Eigen way you have to do the concatenation, store it in a variable and then use that variable. Eigen's way is objectively less versatile as far syntax goes.

This is one of my pet peeves but Eigen is full of stuff like this, and I am getting sick of having to comply to what it wants vs what I want to write.

With that in mind, I am thinking that maybe I can add constructors for the small cases (4 dimensional objects) to make Eigen feel more like glm. However since the class definition is in the source code of eigen, this would imply understanding and modifying its source code, which has the disadvantage of having to maintain that code unless I can merge it to eigen's source, which could take longer than I am willing to wait, and could even not be accepted.

## Actual question

Can I grab a class that was defined somewhere else and create a new constructor?

Comment: Why not free functions?

Comment: It is doable with free functions, but glm has the advantage that its syntax matches the syntax in GLSL. It's not a hard requirement but if I could get Eigen to match that as well then it would make my code more portable between the 2 systems, which is a plus.

Comment: You can still use [Adapter_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Comment: That stops me from freely being able to pass the objects in my code to other code that uses EIgen as the types would no longer be compatible. And it also requires that I manually expose as much if not all of the same functionality as Eigen, which is a tedius process of looking through the source code and figuring out if I have exposed everything.

Comment: You can use the [plugin-mechanism](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) to add constructors to the `Matrix` class. This is only recommended, e.g., while porting code. And if you are happier with glm, then try to extend that with the functionality you are missing ...

Comment: One reason why Eigen does not natively provide this kind of constructors, is that it would be unclear what to do when constructing a `MatrixXd` from to other `MatrixXd` objects: Should they be concatenated horizontally or vertically? Also, if you passed more than two objects, shall they be read row-major or column-major?

Comment: @chtz "then try to extend that with the functionality you are missing" that would mena implementing linear, solvers, cholesky factorizations, sparse matrices... Which is literally months if not years worth of development.

As for concatenation, those ambiguities could always just be specified as default parameters. i.e eigen picks something by default and allows you to configure it. Or it can just allow it for vectors only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is *Extension Functions*. Some languages such as Kotlin [have them](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), but C++ doesn't. So you're out of luck.

If you created your own vector library, it would be no problem, because you could then create a constructor that implicitly converts from other vectors and an `operator` that implicitly converts to other vectors. If you are migrating between libraries and don't need to keep both versions up to date, you could add these two functions and solve almost all compatibility issues.

At least you can define operators outside the classes, like:

```cpp
glm::vec4 operator+(glm::vec4 a, Eigen::Vector4f b) {
    return a + eigen_vector_to_glm_vector(b);
}
```

Comment: Having my own vector class would just add too much code to maintain without good reason, guess I am stuck with using functions and loosing the ability to copy paste my code onto glsl.